# How do XQuery function namespaces work?

Tags: function, namespaces, xquery, saxon

**EDIT**

I want to group together related functions to show that they are related.

If I have `local:f1()` and `local:f2()` then I could just change their names to `local:menu-f1()` and `local:menu-f2()` but is there a mechanism in the XQuery language to group related functions?

**OP**

I am very excited to discover that XQuery functions can be declared in a namespace other than `local:`. Where can I find info about how this works?

Having always declared functions in this way;

```
declare function local:foo() {
   3+4
};
```

.. and used them in this way;

```
local:foo()
```

.. I discover that they can be declared like this;

```
declare namespace baz = "fred:bloggs";
declare function baz:foo() {
   3+4
};
```

.. and used like this;

```
baz:foo()
```

But I can only find reference-like information about `declare namespace` and `declare function` separately, not tutorial-like information about how XQuery function namespaces work in general.

Is there a newbie guide to XQuery function namespaces?

I'm using a Saxon processor - XQuery 1.0.

Comment: There is nothing like "XQuery function namespaces" -- these are just regular XML namespaces and follow all the rules for XML namespaces. Therefore, you should read about and practice using and understanding XML namespaces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are probably using are normal XQuery namespaces - what you probably are looking for are modules. You can put a bunch of functions in its own module namespace like this:

```
module namespace foo = "http://www.myurl.com/foo";

declare function foo:bar($args as item()*) as item()* {
  () (: do something cool :)
};
```

Afterwards you can import the module in you main query and call the function:

```
import module namespace foo = "http://www.myurl.com/foo";

foo:bar(<my-element/>)
```

The problem is, that it is not standardized, how the processor has to find the query. And I don't know how Saxon implements the module resolving mechanism (you should look into the documentation and/or write to the Saxon mailing list).

But most XQuery processors look at the path given by an "at" clause relative from the location of the query. So to have something that should work on most implementations: For example you could store the module in a file named foo.xq and place it into the same directory than your main query and then for the module import you would write:

```
import module namespace foo = "http://www.myurl.com/foo" at "foo.xq";
```

which gives a hint to the XQuery engine where it should look for the module.

You can find some (not a lot at the moment) documentation about this stuff at http://www.xquery.me/ - hope this helps.

**EDIT**

Ok I see, you only want to group your functions. To do that you already figured out everything you need to know. But I still want to emphasize that splitting your query up into modules would probably be the better solution for your use-case (it's just somehow nicer, since your have more modularity and in the upcoming XQuery 3.0 recommendation you will even have the possibility to put stuff like private functions and variables in there). But if your query does not get big, your solution is of course also ok.
You can think about XML namespaces the same way you would think about namespaces in C++. In XQuery, functions, elements, collections, variables, attributes etc can be in an own namespace (again - like in C++). There are some implicitely defined namespaces like xs (the XML Schema namespace where you can find the data types like boolean, integer etc), local (a namespace where you can put in functions so that you are not forced to define your own namespace in a main query), fn (where all functions from the "XQuery 1.0 and XPath 2.0 functions and operators" recommendation are defined). But the prefix of this function is only an alias - you can use whatever you want.
So let's say you have the following code in the prolog of your query:

```
declare namespace blubb = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
```

blubb:integer would be exactly the same type than xs:integer - the same holds for functions:

```
declare namespace l = "http://www.w3.org/2005/xquery-local-functions";
```

With declaring that you can access every function in the local namespace with the "l" prefix (so l:bar() if local:bar() exists).

If you do not type a prefix, XQuery assumes that this function is in the "fn" namespace. This is why bot

```
fn:concat("Hello ", "World!")
```

and

```
concat("Hello ", "World!")
```

are equivalent. You can change this behavior. You could include this line into the prolog:

```
declare default function namespace "http://www.w3.org/2005/xquery-local-functions";
```

which would tell the XQuery processor that you do not want to prefix local functions (so bar() would be equivalent to local:bar()).

I am not sure if I answered your questions or at least was able to bring in some clarity. I do not know about a tutorial for that (since in the beginning it is somehow confusing but in the end you realize that there is not a lot to say about since the mechanisms are much simpler than they look in the first place). The document where I always look up stuff is the recommendation at http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/

If this does not help you please try to qualify and I can try again with an explanation..

Comment: Thanks for your very detailed answer. In my question I neglected to say why I was interested in XQuery namesapces. I've updated my question to better explain what I want.